# SizeToFit method minimum IOS requirement(Support)

Tags: ios, xcode, minimum, sizetofit

simple Question , im trying to understand which minimal ios support SizeToFit method.
I have tried it on a IOS 7 simulator and its seems to work properly.
But according to the docs :

[image]

sample code :

```
numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
```

It support IOS 8+, how is it possible? **Is it safe to use on ios 7?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit) here for `sizeToFit`. It says :

> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

So, don't worry it will work on `iOS7`

Comment: In fact, he's coding in Swift, so there's a sense in seeing this message in Xcode. This should also work on iOS 7, since Swift runs on iOS 7 too. About previous versions, it won't work.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. Any suggestions why the docs(on XCODE) says its 8+?